# How to delete amzon sagemaker studio project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am unable to delete the project in amazon sagemaker studios have tried using the different methods

Comment: Can you add the error that you are observing ?

Comment: It's very annoying when playing with CDK, I need to create new projects every time I run the CDK because the "project name already exists"

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard delete on SageMaker Projects. When you delete them through the SDK or CLI ([API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteProject.html)), it updates the status of the project to 'Deleted'. You can extend the left pane to see the status, like the screenshot below. [image: Studio projects pane]

Answer (score 0):

Projects in Amazon SageMaker Studio were deployed using Amazon Service Catalog, if you cannot delete the project in Amazon SageMaker, you can go to Service Catalog and try and remove it there.

In Amazon Service Catalog, select provisioned products, change the access filter in the top right from User to Account and you should see your projects. Delete them there.